# Swift: programmatically align labels for different IOS screen sizes

Tags: ios, swift, cocos2d-iphone, label

I'm new to Swift and ios development. I have 6 labels and a horizontal SKScene in my App. I would like to align those 6 labels beautifully and automatically. Now I have fixed the positions and the alignment always looks awful on some screen size while good on other.

I have not used storyboards or other graphical editors for building the ui but everything is done in code. Therefore I'm looking for a programmatic solution (code examples) for handling the alignment.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to place them in the middle of the screen horizontally, but give them different y positions, you could just do something like this for each label:

```
label.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) * 0.80)
```

To place them at different y positions, just multiply by the maxY by a different decimal number. This way, all of the labels are aligned along the x-axis and appear at different y-positions, like a column and they will appear this way on every screen size because they are positioned relative to the screen size and not in a fixed position.

Answer (score 1):

You can align the labels (lets say at the center of the screen) like this.

```
var label1 = UILabel(CGRectMake: 0, 0, 200, 40)
label1.center = CGPointMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width/2, 30)

var label2 = UILabel(CGRectMake: 0, 0, 200, 40)
label2.center = CGPointMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width/2, label1.center.y + 30)
```

and so on. Just reference the main screen bounds and not static points for alignment, so that they are centered in any screen size.

Comment: From what I understand, the author is dealing with SceneKit or SpriteKit (or Cocos2D).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for the ambiguity of my question. I have done just this meaning I use "bounds.size.width/2" style for adding the labels. I still call this hardcoding. I have 6 labels in a row so the proportions between different labels and screen edges vary with different devices. To my understanding IOS has an automatic "proportioning" mechanism but I'm clueless to how it works. I must edit my question.

Comment: Or for example is there a container that I could set all the labels into, hard code the proportional spaces to look good betweeb the labels and then center the container with "bounds.size.width/2"?

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing was to create an empty SKSprite to which I included the SKLabels. Now I can control by the pixed the distances between labels but align the top-level sprite in the middle of the screen despite screen size.